# How heating of copper sulphate pentahydrate (blue vitriol) can be explained?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, coordination-compounds, hydrogen-bond, salt

[image]

The chemical formula of copper sulphate pentahydrate, $\ce{CuSO4\cdot 5H2O}$ does not give information about its true structure because it's only an empirical formula.

It forms a network solid. Two units of sulphate ions are bonded with central metal ion $\ce{Cu(II)}$. But each $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ ions are bonded to two $\ce{Cu^2+}$. Hence, the average number of sulphate ion per cupric ion is one. Similarly, the average number of water molecules per $\ce{CuSO4}$ unit is five. Out of which, one molecule is H-bonded.

Upon heating, first it loses two molecules of water then two more molecules of water and finally the remaining one in following steps:$^1$

$\underset{\underset{\text{(Crystal)}}{\text{Blue}}}{\ce{CuSO4\cdot 5H2O (s)}}\ce{\color{red}{->[63 ^\circ C][-2H2O]}}\underset{\text{Light blue}}{\ce{CuSO4\cdot 3H2O (s)}}\ce{\color{red}{->[109 ^\circ C][-2H2O]}}\underset{\text{Very light blue}}{\ce{CuSO4\cdot H2O (s)}}\ce{\color{red}{->[200 ^\circ C][-H2O]}}\underset{\underset{\text{(amorphous)}}{\text{Grey-white}}}{\ce{CuSO4 (s)}}$

1- Why removal of water molecules following this pattern: 2, 2, 1? Every hydrated salt follows a pattern, e.g., sodium carbonate decahydrate loses 9 molecules of water at once to form monohydrate.

2- In $\ce{CuSO4\cdot H2O}$, the water molecule must be hydrogen bonded but why the coordinated bonded water molecules are breaking bonds prior to H-bonded water? Coordinate bonds are much stronger than H-bonds even if we consider that one water molecule is making multiple H-bonds.

3- What can we say about the structure of $\ce{CuSO4\cdot 3H2O}$?

**Reference**

1. Page 766, Inorganic Chemistry (4E) By Catherine Housecroft, Pearson- 2012, ISBN: 9780273742784

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/71980/why-is-anhydrous-copperii-sulfate-white-while-the-pentahydrate-is-blue-even-t

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/110728/hydrate-decomposition-equation-steps

Comment: That's pretty much a duplicate of the second one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hydrate decomposition equation steps](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/110728/hydrate-decomposition-equation-steps)

Comment: No, as there are few more queries mentioned in this question and the answer ended with "In reality many assumptions suitable for estimation of melting points of molecular crystals, e.g. regarding the number of bonds and their types don't work well for ionic crystals ..."

Comment: Note that IPUAC's preferred spelling is "*sulfate*". [IUPAC prohibits use of dative bonds (arrows) to represent coordination](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020277). This is not "*polymeric structure*", rather a network solid. The crystal structure of $\ce{CuSO4 · 3H2O}$ (bonattite) is freely available at multiple sources, e.g. see https://www.mindat.org/min-718.html.

Comment: @andselisk So in bonattite, the coordination no. of Cu(II) is 4.